# Why is the last case of my switch statement getting hit?

Tags: java, android

The last case of my switch statement in my Java app is always getting hit. How can I make this work properly?

```
public void onClick(View v) {       
    Random r = new Random();
    int x=r.nextInt(4-1) + 1;
    switch (x)
    {
    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.image1);
    case 2:
        setContentView(R.layout.image2);
    case 3:
        setContentView(R.layout.image3);
    case 4:
        setContentView(R.layout.image4);
```

Answer (score 11):

Case statements will 'fall through' in most languages without a break statement. You just need to add one to each case. Like this:

```
case 1:
    setContentView(R.layout.image1);
    break;
case 2:
    setContentView(R.layout.image2);
    break;
case 3:
    setContentView(R.layout.image3);
    break;
case 4:
    setContentView(R.layout.image4);
    break;
```

Answer (score 5):

You're falling through your case statements.  You need to `break`.

```
switch (x)
{
  case 1:
    setContentView(R.layout.image1);
    break;
  case 2:
    setContentView(R.layout.image2);
    break;
  case 3:
    setContentView(R.layout.image3);
    break;
  case 4:
    setContentView(R.layout.image4);
    break;
}
```

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have to `break;` every switch statements you have. If you don't break the statement then the next case will be hit (and so one until the last with a break).

```
    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.image1);
        break;
    case 2:
        setContentView(R.layout.image2);
        break;
    case 3:
        setContentView(R.layout.image3);
        break;
    case 4:
        setContentView(R.layout.image4);
        break;
    default:
        //Anything you want;
    break;
```

And... it's a good programming practice to use the default case (will be used if none of the cases is hit)